TreeView: prevent horizontal scrolling when selecting an item
Here is what is happening:

Desired outcome:

When selecting any item no horizontal scrolling should occur (even if the item is too big to show)
Solution must work with virtualization
Horizontal scrollbar works
User can scroll horizontally with mouse or keys if available

There are some brutal hacks like handling the RequestBringIntoView event but this is not desirable as it breaks programmatic scrolling.
What to do?

To control your horizontal scroll do the following (the name of my treeview is Internal). You mentioned that RequestBringIntoView is a nasty hack. Unfortunately you cant have it both ways. Open Windows Explorer and what you will find is that the Navigation Pane does not support a horizontal scroll (from Windows 10 anyway).
public ScrollViewer ScrollViewer { get; set; } = null;    
private double HorizontalScrollPosition { get; set; } = 0.0;
private bool ResetHorizontalScrollPosition { get; set; } = false;

private void Internal_RequestBringIntoView(object sender, RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs e)
{
    if (ScrollViewer == null) SetScrollViewer();
    ResetHorizontalScrollPosition = true;
    HorizontalScrollPosition = ScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset;
}
private void SetScrollViewer()
{
    ScrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)Internal.Template.FindName("_tv_scrollviewer_", Internal);
    if (ScrollViewer != null) ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged += new ScrollChangedEventHandler(ScrollChanged);
}
private void ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ResetHorizontalScrollPosition) ScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(HorizontalScrollPosition);
    ResetHorizontalScrollPosition = false;
}

Also, consider a review of your navigation. For example:
--Dynamics 365
  -- Business Central
    -- Premium Partner Sandbox
    -- Team Member (Embedded)
  -- Team Members
-- Internal Administrator

